# Do concepts in probability help us understand when an analogical inference is acceptable?

Tags: probability, inference

I'm a philosophy undergraduate. I've recently read about analogical inferences. When making inferences by analogy, we observe that many of the properties of the analogues are the same, then infer that the rest of the properties are probably the same.

For example, an analogy between sets of the vital properties of two plants:

- Premise 1: a tree needs roots in the ground, sun, leaves, and water to live;
- Premise 2: a weed needs roots in the ground, sun, and leaves to live,
- Conclusion 1: a weed probably needs water to live too.

I also read that the more properties one can predicate of both analogues, the stronger the analogy between them. I don't know enough about probability and defeasible inference to discern whether that claim is accurate.

To me, it seems as though what warrants inductive inferences (on which statisticians are experts) warrants analogical inference: If we regard the set of vital properties of each plant as a population, and regard each vital property of each plant as members of that population, and regard the set of vital properties mentioned in the premises of the analogy as a sample, then at first blush it seems that we could justify the inference that 'if both plants have all the vital properties in the sample, then both plants probably have the same vital properties.'

But if that's an acceptable inference, what makes it acceptable? Are there concepts in probability that can help explain why that's the case?

Thank you.

Comment: You have a better chance of philosophising with Bayesian probabilities. The analogy of properties and sample observations does not work. Consider observations of height of students. This is the sample. All data is of the same kind. Your properties are more like height, weight, race... these are different variables.

Comment: I don't think they do really. Reading Nelson Goodman might.

Comment: @Aksakal, Suppose you were looking at two sets of Rubik's cube moves that were used to solve the cube. The more moves the two sets have in common, the less likely a divergence of the rest of the moves becomes. For instance, if they both shared 99 moves/100 and they both solve the cube, then it seems very unlikely that the last move could differ. If they shared 98 moves/100 the it would be more likely, but still unlikely that they would differ. If they shared 97 moves... (cont)

Comment: @Aksakal That idea seems to applicable to other systems - e.g. bi-pedal locomotion. If you took only the necessary elements of two systems of bi-pedal locomotion, it seems impossible that one of the two systems could have only one *necessary* difference...

Comment: the reason why I started with a reference to Bayesian is that I noticed that philosophers seem to relate to this approach. based on the discussions during my last philosophy course, it has something to do with subjectivity of probabilities in Bayesian approach. there's more to philosophize around. in natural world probabilities are objective, kind of boring to them.

Comment: @Aksakal yes, data collection is definitely not something philosophers do well. That said, I read that Bayesian probabilities work especially well with predicate logic, that may be another aspect of its appeal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analogical reasoning is a weaker form of argumentation than probabilistic reasoning, in that it is based on *plausibility* and *defeasibility*. As such, any inference from analogical reasoning is less secure than a probabilistic argument, which is, in turn, less secure than a deductive argument.

When you make a defeasible argument, you are implicitly assuming that its premises are reasonable. In analogical reasoning, the key assumption is that properties occur in clusters, not independently of one another. The probabilistic version of this (which is a stronger, more data intensive argument) is:

- Let $\Omega$ be the set of properties possessed by a "reference object", X.
- Let Y be the "comparison object", which has properties K.
- Let S be a strict subset of the properties of X, i.e., $S\subset \Omega$
- Then, the probabilistic version of the analogical argument is: $P(\Omega \in K|S \in K) \space \dot\propto \frac{\#S}{\#\Omega} $

Where $\dot \propto$ means "approximately proportional to", to indicate the the relation may not be strictly linear.

With regard to warrant, since probabilistic reasoning is stronger than plausible/defeasible reasoning, then of course anything that warrants probabilistic reasoning also warrants plausible reasoning, but not vice versa, since the latter is more of a *prima facie* form of reasoning.

Comment: How would you calculate P in your example? I like your definition of plausibility (prima facie probable). Just to clarify, do you take defeasible inference to denote *non-deductive inference* or something else?

Comment: @Hal To answer your second question first: Yes - I follow Douglas Walton's taxonomy, which defines a "ladder of certainty": Deductive > Probabilistic > Probable/defesible. So defeasible inference is a type of non-deductive inference. As for your first question: My post was more of a conceptual outline - the actual probabilities need to be empirically or theoretically determined from some prior knowledge. This was why I said the probabilistic version was a stronger and more data intensive form of analogical reasoning. The calculation of P will be context dependent.

Comment: @Hal (con'td) The only requirement I put on the probability function is that it is an increasing function of the number of known common attributes between X and Y.

Comment: @Hal did my comments address your concerns?

Comment: Yes they did. I should have accepted. Sorry, I forgot. Thanks again.